# Download Report Scan from Copyleaks

Tags: java, spring-boot, webhooks, plagiarism-detection, copyleaks-api

in order to detect plagiarism, I'm using Copyleaks API.
I successfully scan the file referring to [this helpful link](https://github.com/Copyleaks/Java-Plagiarism-Checker/blob/master/src/main/java/example/Example.java).

By running this main class, I got this trace:

> Logged successfully!
> Token:
> models.response.CopyleaksAuthToken@411f53a0Submitting a new file...
> Send to scanning
> You will be notified, using your webhook, once the scan was completed.
>
> command failed with status Code:409
> jdk.internal.net.http.common.MinimalFuture@131ef10[Completed normally] (id=125)
>
> models.exceptions.CommandException: command failed with status Code:409
> jdk.internal.net.http.common.MinimalFuture@131ef10[Completed normally] (id=125)
> at classes.Copyleaks.export(Copyleaks.java:314)
> at *** (Example.java:153)

It seems stuck on

> Copyleaks.export(token, scanId, exportId, exportModel);
> Looks like not recognize the **https://your.server/webhook**

I have created a webhook via pipeline

After execute the API POST via postman https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/downloads/scanId/export/exportId

I got [204 No Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzfhb.png)

after execute the API GET https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/downloads/lol5/report.pdf,
I got the PDF uploaded on Uploaded: 29/1/2019 and not the expected one.

Have you please any idea about solving this issue ?.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Googling 'copyleaks webhooks' leads you to [this](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/webhooks) page which describes how Copyleaks uses webhooks and requirements to support webhooks. If you don't want to use webhooks try not passing ```new SubmissionWebhooks("https://your.server/webhook?event={{STATUS}}")```.

Comment: Hello Sir @Lee Greiner, Thanks a lot for your reply, So it's possible to use copyleaks without webhook.I commented the `new SubmissionProperties`, and then `CopyleaksFileSubmissionModel model = new CopyleaksFileSubmissionModel(BASE64_FILE_CONTENT, FILENAME, null);`, as result the method **submitFile** failed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting HTTP response code 409 (Conflict) when submitting the file.

Please take a look on [this documentation page](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/scans/submit/url). According to it, you will get Conflict problem if the scan ID you trying to submit, is already submitted before.

Assuming you are using the sample code, in order to change the scan id - you will need to change this line into something unique:

```
String scanId = "unique-id-here";
```

Comment: Hello Sir @No1Lives4Ever, thanks a lot for your reply. Sorry, but it's not a conflict problem. I already submit the scan with success. I made some updates on my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Hello @Sim, your problem is not clear to me. The Copyleaks Export endpoint is working on async way. Which mean, the PDF file, for example, will be "pushed" to your endpoint. So my question is why you calling the endpoint https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/downloads/lol5/report.pdf ?